# Django 1.5.1 "'STDOUT_LINE' is not defined" when running tests

Tags: python, django, tdd

When I run tests in Django for my applications I have the following exception

`.......NameError: global name 'STDOUT_LINE' is not defined`

There're only 9 test methods in the test case.

What may cause this problem, may be someone already faced this kind of problem?

#### Verbose output

```
$ : ./manage.py test profile
/Users/sultan/.virtualenvs/yoda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/util.py:14: DeprecationWarning: The compiler package is deprecated and removed in Python 3.x.
  from compiler.consts import CO_GENERATOR

nosetests --verbosity 1 profile --verbosity=2 --with-snot --with-xtraceback --with-coverage --cover-package=profile
/Users/sultan/.virtualenvs/yoda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py:53: RuntimeWarning: SQLite received a naive datetime (2013-04-22 11:19:12.808338) while time zone support is active.
  RuntimeWarning)

Creating test database for alias 'default'...
Test page to create order ... ok
Test with anonymous user, index page should give a login form ... ok
Test with anonymous user, index page should give a login form ... ok
Test drivers list ... ok
Test operators list ... ok
Test if login works ... ok
Test if user logged in as manager will be redirected to /manager page ... ok
Test if user logged in as operator will be redirected to /operator page ... NameError: global name 'STDOUT_LINE' is not defined
```

#### Update tests for urls

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.test import TestCase
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

from profile.tests.factories import UserFactory
from profile.models import ROLE_OPERATOR, ROLE_USER
from profile.models import ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_DRIVER, ROLE_MANAGER


class TestUrls(TestCase):
    """ Test common project wide urls """

    def setUp(self):
        self.user = UserFactory.create(role=ROLE_USER)
        self.admin = UserFactory.create(role=ROLE_ADMIN, is_superuser=True)
        self.driver = UserFactory.create(role=ROLE_DRIVER)
        self.manager = UserFactory.create(role=ROLE_MANAGER)
        self.operator = UserFactory.create(role=ROLE_OPERATOR)

    def get(self, url, follow=True):
        return self.client.get(url, follow=follow)

    def login(self):
        self.client.login(username=self.manager.username, password='pass')

    def test_index_page_login(self):
        """ Test with anonymous user, index page should give a login form """
        res = self.get(reverse('profile:index'))
        self.assertContains(res, 'Login')
        self.assertEqual(res.status_code, 200)

    def test_login(self):
        """ Test if login works """
        res = self.get(reverse('profile:login'))
        res2 = self.get(reverse('profile:login'), follow=False)
        self.assertEqual(res.status_code, 200)
        self.assertEqual(res2.status_code, 302)

    def test_operator_redirect(self):
        """
        Test if user logged in as operator
        will be redirected to /operator page
        """
        self.login()
        res = self.get(reverse('profile:index'))
        self.assertTrue('/operator' in res.request['PATH_INFO'])

    def test_manager_redirect(self):
        """
        Test if user logged in as manager
        will be redirected to /manager page
        """
        self.login()
        res = self.get(reverse('profile:index'))
        self.assertTrue('/manager' in res.request['PATH_INFO'])

    def test_references_page(self):
        """ Test references """
        self.login()
        res = self.get(reverse('profile:reference'))
        self.assertEqual(res.status_code, 200)
        self.assertTemplateUsed('profile/reference.html')

    def test_list_drivers(self):
        """ Test drivers list """
        self.login()
        res = self.get(reverse('profile:drivers'))
        self.assertEqual(res.status_code, 200)
        self.assertTemplateUsed('profile/driver_list.html')

    def test_list_operators(self):
        """ Test operators list """
        self.login()
        res = self.get(reverse('profile:operators'))
        self.assertEqual(res.status_code, 200)
        self.assertTemplateUsed('profile/operator_list.html')

    def test_error500(self):
        """ Test with anonymous user, index page should give a login form """
        res = self.get(reverse('profile:error500'))
        self.assertEqual(res.status_code, 200)

    def test_create_order_page(self):
        """ Test page to create order """
        res = self.get(reverse('profile:new_order'), follow=False)
        self.assertEqual(res.status_code, 302)

        self.login()

        res = self.get(reverse('profile:new_order'))
        self.assertEqual(res.status_code, 200)
```

Comment: Please, note how do you run your tests and, if possible, show your test case.

Comment: Please post the full traceback too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved it was because of assertion failed at

```
def test_operator_redirect(self):
    """ Test if user logged in as operator will be redirected to /operator page """
    self.login(self.operator)
    res = self.get(reverse('taxi:index'))
    self.assertTrue('/operator' in res.request['PATH_INFO'])
```

So I changed `self.login` method and it worked though this error appears again if `self.assertTrue` fails

```
def login(self, user):
    self.client.login(username=user.username, password='pass')
```